# Select only records without future dates via join

Tags: mysql, join

There are 2 tables: events and dates. One event could have multiple dates.

I would like to select only those events which don't have corresponding dates in the future.

I tried the following query

```
SELECT e.id_event FROM events e RIGHT JOIN dates d ON e.id_event=d.id_event AND !(d.date > NOW())
```

but it shows events which has both dates in past and in future.

Sample data

Events table

| id_event |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Dates table

| id_event | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-10-10 |
| 1 | 2030-10-10 |
| 2 | 2020-10-10 |

The query should return only one record, id_event =  2.

Comment: Right joins are best avoided in my view as are ! operators. Please add sample data and desired outcome as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways to do this

```
create table t1(id_event int, date date);

insert into t values (1),(2);
insert into t1 values (1,'2020-01-01'),(1,'2030-01-01'),(2,'2020-01-01');

SELECT e.id_event 
FROM t e 
left JOIN t1 d ON e.id_event=d.id_event 
group by e.ID_event having max(d.date) < now()
;

SELECT e.id_event 
FROM t e 
left JOIN t1 d ON e.id_event=d.id_event 
where not exists(select 1 from t1 t2 where t2.id_event = d.id_event and t2.date > now())
;
```

First may not be useful if you intend to take more columns from either table..

Comment: The first one is the best for me, I only used RIGHT JOIN to exclude events without dates :))) Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query ([Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k1udY1LSMfLyhMZxSt8Rvw/1)):

```
SELECT evt.id_event
FROM events evt 
WHERE evt.id_event NOT IN (
  SELECT e.id_event 
  FROM events e 
  INNER JOIN dates d 
  ON e.id_event=d.id_event 
  AND d.date > CURDATE()
);
```

Here, at first, all event ids with future dates are found out, and then event ids are selected which are not in the previously found out event ids.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It works well, but sorry I need the query without subquery for my task.

Answer (score 0):

`NOW()`is timestamp : you want `CURDATE`
try

```
SELECT e.id_event 
FROM events e RIGHT 
JOIN dates d 
ON e.id_event=d.id_event AND d.date <= CURDATE();
```

`<= CURDATE()` is before or including today which is the same thing as NOT IN THE FUTURE.

Comment: Your query would return the records which have dates in the past. I need records that don't have dates in the future.

Comment: <= CURDATE() will return date before and including today

Comment: @kendle 1 should not be returned because it has a future date..